# AEM Dispatcher vhost settings with rewrite rule is not working

Tags: apache, content-management-system, aem, dispatcher

I am unable to get the rewrite working on Dispatcher module of AEM.
Following is what's happening with my configuration:

Dispatcher configuration:

**Snippet of my httpd.conf**

```
LoadModule dispatcher_module modules/mod_dispatcher.so

    <IfModule disp_apache2.c>
      DispatcherConfig conf/dispatcher.any
      DispatcherLog    logs/dispatcher.log
      DispatcherLogLevel 3
      DispatcherNoServerHeader 0
      DispatcherDeclineRoot 0
      DispatcherUseProcessedURL 0
      DispatcherPassError 0
    </IfModule>


    <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName mobile.example.com.au
      DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/content/mobile"
      RewriteEngine  on
      RewriteRule    ^/(.*)\.html$  /content/mobile/$1.html [PT]
    <Directory "/var/www/html/content/mobile">
      <IfModule disp_apache2.c>
        SetHandler dispatcher-handler
        ModMimeUsePathInfo On
    </IfModule>
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride None
     # AddType text/html .html
     # AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .html
     # Options +Includes
    </Directory>

    </VirtualHost>

    ......
```

Now, if I try to access the mobile.example.com.au/home.html, it shows up this 404 and says no content:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /content/mobile/home.html was
>   not found on this server.

Though I am able to hit the page directly by using the full path:
http://mobile.example.com.au/content/mobile/home.html and the page is rendered.

What am I missing here? Is it something to do with the Document root?

Also, how do we set the default landing page for mobile.example.com.au to show up home.html.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check rewrite logs to see how request is flowing?
Also, to set default landing page, you can use following rule

```
RewriteRule ^/$ /content/mobile/home.html [PT,L]
```

Comment: Also, please check if you have enabled rewrite module in httpd conf :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to change this line:

`DispatcherUseProcessedURL 0`

to

`DispatcherUseProcessedURL 1`

... so that Dispatcher uses the rewritten URL for filter checks, cache structure, and the request to AEM. You'll also need to add the RewriteRule as Mohit suggested, probably as the first rule - but only if you want / to show the /home.html page.

See also: [Adobe documentation on Dispatcher configuration](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/dispatcher/disp-install.html#Apache%20Web%20Server%20-%20Configure%20Apache%20Web%20Server%20for%20Dispatcher)